# How to update NGRX related data?

Tags: angular, typescript, ngrx

I have two models, a one-to-many relationship:

```
export interface GroupModel {
  id: number;
  name: string;
  userIds?: number[];
}
export interface UserModel {
  id: number;
  name: string;
  groupId?: number;
}
```

The problem is, when I update either of them with an effect, the change is not reflected in the corresponding association:

**groups.effects.ts**

```
updateGroup$ = createEffect(() =>
  this.actions$.pipe(
    ofType(GroupsActions.updateGroup),
    concatMap(({ group }) =>
      this.groupsService.update(group).pipe(
        map(() =>
          GroupsAPIActions.groupUpdatedSuccess({
            update: { id: group.id, changes: group },
          })
        ),
        catchError((error) =>
          of(GroupsAPIActions.groupUpdatedFail({ message: error }))
        )
      )
    )
  )
);
```

**users.effects.ts**

```
updateUser$ = createEffect(() =>
  this.actions$.pipe(
    ofType(UsersActions.updateUser),
    concatMap(({ user }) =>
      this.usersService.update(user).pipe(
        map(() =>
          UsersAPIActions.userUpdatedSuccess({
            update: { id: user.id, changes: user },
          })
        ),
        catchError((error) =>
          of(UsersAPIActions.userUpdatedFail({ message: error }))
        )
      )
    )
  )
);
```

My reducer update methods look like the following:

```
on(
  GroupsActions.groupStation,
  (state) =>
    ({
      ...state,
      loading: true,
      errorMessage: '',
    })
),
on(GroupsAPIActions.groupUpdatedSuccess, (state, { update }) =>
  groupsAdapter.updateOne(update, {
    ...state,
    loading: false,
  })
),
on(
  GroupsAPIActions.groupUpdatedFail,
  (state, { message }) =>
    ({
      ...state,
      loading: false,
      errorMessage: message,
    })
)
```

In summary, let's say that we have the following models:

```
groups: [
  { id: 1, name: "Group 1", userIds?: [1, 2] }
];
users: [
  { id: 1, name: "User 1", groupId: 1 }
  { id: 2, name: "User 2", groupId: 1 }
];
```

And I then call the dispatch method where we want to remove user 2 from the group:

```
this.store.dispatch(UserActions.updateUser({
    user: { id: 2, name: "User 2", groupId: undefined }
});
```

I want group 1 to remove the `userId` from the `userIds` array as well:

```
{ id: 1, name: "Group 1", userIds?: [1] }
```

What is a good approach to achieve this? Is there a standard way or do I need to write code to handle this manually?

**Edit:**

I wrote the following code manually for the `groupsReducer`, but this seems a lot of code for such a trivial task.

```
on(UsersAPIActions.userUpdatedSuccess, (state, { update }) => {
  const userId = +update.id;
  const newGroupId = update.changes.groupId;
  const allGroups = selectAll(state);

  // Find the group that contains the userId
  const groupToUpdate = allGroups.find((group: GroupModel) =>
    group.userIds.includes(userId)
  );

  const updateGroupChanges = {} as Partial<GroupModel>;

  // If Group with updated user in it is found
  if (groupToUpdate) {
    // UpdatedUser has a group
    if (newGroupId) {
      // A: If the group is the same: do nothing (user still belongs to the same group)
      if (groupToUpdate.id === newGroupId) return state;
      
      // B: If the group is different, remove the user from the old group and add it to the new one
      const oldGroupChanges = {
        userIds: groupToUpdate.userIds.filter((id) => id !== newGroupId),
      } as Partial<GroupModel>;
      const newGroupChanges = {
        userIds: [...groupToUpdate.userIds, newGroupId],
      } as Partial<GroupModel>;

      console.log(`Group ${groupToUpdate.id}: Moving user ${userId} to group ${newGroupId}`);
      
      // Update both groups
      return groupsAdapter.updateMany(
        [
          { id: groupToUpdate.id, changes: oldGroupChanges },
          { id: newGroupId, changes: newGroupChanges },
        ],
        { ...state }
      );
    }

    // UpdatedUser has no group: Remove user from group
    console.log(`Group ${groupToUpdate.id}: Removing user ${userId}`);

    updateGroupChanges.userIds = groupToUpdate.userIds.filter(
      (id) => id !== newGroupId
    );
  }
  // No group is found where the user currently belongs to
  else {
    // If the updated user also has no group id set: Do nothing
    if (!newGroupId) return state;

    // If the updated user has a group id set, add user to that group
    const newGroup = selectGroupById(newGroupId)(state);
    if (!newGroup) {
      console.warn(`Group ${newGroupId}: Not found! Could not add user ${userId}`);
      return state;
    }

    console.log(`Group ${newGroupId}: Adding user ${userId}`);

    updateGroupChanges.userIds = [...newGroup.userIds, userId];
  }

  return groupsAdapter.updateOne(
    {
      id: newGroupId,
      changes: updateGroupChanges,
    } as Update<GroupModel>,
    { ...state } satisfies GroupsEntityState
  );
}),
```

Comment: Looks like there is no standard way. Maybe this library https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngrx-entity-relationship from this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/61935815/6610613 can be useful?

Comment: Just remember that you can use the same action in different reducers. It should be trivial

Comment: @maxime1992 I have edited the OP. Is this what you mean or am I thinking in the wrong direction?

Comment: Sorry, there's way too much code for me to be able to take the time to help you any further. If you want to increase your response rate, make sure to make a **minimal** repro, stripping out all the unnecessary context and pin pointing to the only thing you're asking. Not saying that in a mean way but I really don't have that much time to grasp the context. If you don't take the time and effort to make a minimal repro and just put all your code, you just shift that burden to people reading your question, and you'll have less chances of people answering

Comment: Thanks for the comment. Well what you said is basically my point, because what it does is simply adding, moving or removing the user from/to a group with some checks and logging in between, nothing else. It feels so bloated and I feel this could be done way more efficiently, I just don't know how (yet), that is my question.

Answer (score 1):

To update both states the reducers will listen to both actions to update their own state.

For example. The group reduced will listen for `groupUpdatedSuccess` (as it is now), and also for the action `userUpdatedSuccess`.

The same applies for the user reducer, which listens for both `userUpdatedSuccess` and `groupUpdatedSuccess` actions.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your comment, I read some of your blogs :) I'm fairly new to NGRX. If I understood correctly, I need to add an `on(UserActions.userUpdatedSuccess, ...)` in the `groupsReducer` and a `on(GroupsActions.groupUpdatedSuccess, ...)` in the `userReducer`? I'm not sure how to go from there, I'm using `EntityAdapters` for both states, so I cannot access the entities internally right? Can you perhaps expand your answer with some small code examples to clarify? That would be great, thank you :)

Comment: I have modified the OP with the reducer `on(UserActions.userUpdatedSuccess, ...)` in the `groupsReducer`. Is this what you mean? This seems an awful lot of code for such a trivial task, especially when the models are larger. It basically does the same thing over and over. Is there a better way where I can perhaps leverage the ngrx library?

Comment: That's exactly what I meant. I didn't take a closer look but based on the length I would say that this isn't good. Another way is to remove the property from the group or from the user. Using selectors you'll still be able to combine both states. Personally I would remove the userId array from the group, but I don't know enough to be sure that's the right way.
Maybe that the `updateMany` of the adapter can also be of help.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. I rewrote it like you said and it looks a lot cleaner now. A small followup question: Is it 'allowed' to use the selectors from the adapter in the reducer? If not, how can I search for entities that match a certain pattern? For instance, I want to check in the `GroupsEntityState` whether some group has a `userId` that equals some value. How can I best approach this?